# Find a folder by name and recursively set it's childrens folders permission to 755

Tags: linux, bash, find

Im trying to pipe the result of `find . -type d -name 'uploads'` into another find function to then find all the child folders and set the permission, but it's not accepting it.

Can anyone help? What I want to do is find a folder called 'uploads', and all the child folders set their permissions to 755, and all the files to 777.

Comment: Do you want to change all child folders and files recursively, or just the first level?

Comment: I'd like to recursively chmod them.

Comment: @dotty If you actually wanted to recursively chmod them, the recursive `chmod -R` would have been the correct solution already.  You want something a little different by treating files and folders differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not particularly elegant, but a while loop will do the job (unless you have folders with newlines in the name or something, in which case `xargs` or `parallel` would be a better choice)

```
find . -type d -name 'uploads' | while read d; do chmod -R 755 "$d"; done
```

... with xargs, you can only do the single command, but that seems to be all you need

```
find . -type d -name 'uploads' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -R 755
```

**E:** To follow the request to make all the sub-directories 755 and files 777, the while loop will do it:

```
 find . -type d -name 'uploads' | while read d; do 
    find "$d/" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755; 
    find "$d/" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777; done
```

Comment: I changed the `chmod -R 755 "$d"` to `echo "$d"` to check what folders are found, but only the uploads folder is found. I need all of it's child folders.

Comment: Ah, you need something a little more complex than the straight recursive chmod (which will set all folders and files to 755).  Another find will do it; let me edit it in.

Comment: @zebediah49 You should have a `-prune` on the left side of the pipe. Otherwise you have recursion on both sides, which you don't need. Also `read` can split on `$'\0'` just as easily as `xargs`. i.e. `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $"\0' d; do...`